# How do I Specify the Scientific Notation Power in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

In Google Sheets when I enter

```
10E-12
```

in a cell formatted for scientific notation, it automatically turns the number into

```
1E-11
```

Though technically correct, this is really annoying when comparing numbers between cells. Is there a way to specify the power to which the number should be raised in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To specify power of exponent, such as to powers of 3, 6, 9, etc, specify the number of places in the format.

e.g.

`##0.00#E+##`

Note that there are 3 places on the left of the decimal and 3 places on the right of the decimal.

The powers will increase or decrease by multiples of 3.

The exponential display can be formatted as you wish with 0 or #.

[image]

Comment: Microsoft Excel seems to obey these formats, too. ##0.00#E+##
##0E+#
##0E#
etc

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the cell(s)
2. Click on Format > Number > More formats > Custom number format...
3. On the box write something like `#0.0E+00`
4. Click Apply button

Note: The leading `#` is to set an optional digit

Reference

- [Format numbers in a spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there also a way to go in the other direction? (i.e. if I want 8E-13 to display as 0.8E-12)

Comment: @Bunji Try `0.0E+00`

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this works. It still shows up as 8.0E-13

Answer (score 0):

**`1.79769E+308`** is the maximum number that Google Sheets is able to output. Respectively **`-1.79769E+308`** is the negative value. Anything higher than that will output into error or gets down-corrected by Google Sheets.

Raising on the power in Google Sheets is done with **`^`** symbol like:

```
=25^7
```




```
=999^99
```